# Simple modular arithmetic question

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Can someone please give a clear explanation on how from
$(41)(59)x\equiv x\pmod {78}$ and
 $(41)(59)x\equiv 123\pmod {78}$
we get 
$x\equiv 123\pmod {78}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $41 \times 59 = 2419 \equiv 1 \pmod{78}$. Hence, we have
$$41 \times 59 \times x \pmod{78} \equiv (78k+1)x \pmod{78} \equiv x \pmod{78}$$
By the same arguement, we have that
$$41 \times 59 \times x \equiv 123 \pmod{78} \implies x\equiv 123 \pmod{78}$$

Answer (score 3):

Congruence satisfies transitivity; that is, if $a\equiv b$ and $b\equiv c$, then $a\equiv c$.